# How to prep for the Geulah

Tags: gentiles, messiah, noachide-laws

As a non-Jew, how can I prepare for the coming of the Messiah and
what are the necessary steps that one must take in order to be ready for redemption?

I look forward to your answers!

Comment: Comparative religion? Why? Because it has the word "non-Jew"?

Comment: Interesting question! I'm not really familiar with Jewish sources that discuss PREPARATION for the eschatological process from the perspective of non-Jews. I would presume that being as righteous an individual as possible (both in character and in practice of Noahide law) is the first part. Not really sure what comes after that, though.

Answer (score 3):

A [Chabad article](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/dailywisdom_cdo/aid/2955573/jewish/Sunday-The-Noahide-Redemption.htm)  contains the  following paragraph:

> Furthermore, in the Messianic future, the non-Jewish nations will be
>   refined and no longer oppose the lifestyle and world-vision of the
>   Torah. By approaching the nations of the world with the option to
>   accept the entire Torah, G‑d implanted within them the receptivity to
>   both their present obligation to accept the Torah’s authority over
>   them – obligating them in the Noahide laws – as well as their future
>   acceptance of the Torah’s world-vision, transforming them into active
>   participants in the final Redemption.

So first the Noahides have to “accept the Torah’s authority over them – obligating them in the Noahide laws” then prepare themselves to accept the “Torah’s world-vision" which I understand to include the philosphic conclusions derived from the Torah.

Answer (score 0):

An important aspect of gentile geulah is putting mashiac in his right clothes.  Currently mashiac is said to sit as a tsarat imprisoned at the gates of Rome.

As well, if the gentile world is to merit the coming of mashiac ben David who will rectify all the world, as opposed to mashiac ben Yosef who plays the role of tzaddiq and atones with his life, bringing many back to Torah and turning hearts to Israel and allowing Jacob, as firstborn, to fulfill his role in the world, which is to bring the spiritual truths of Torah into physicality as a demonstration to us all in wisdom, understanding, knowledge, mercy, justice, beauty.  Having these in place allows for us to accept the perfect balance of dominance and empathy that G-d brings into the world.  In allowing such, we prepare our hearts for receiving G-d's kingship in our lives and the world, demonstrating to G-d that it is appropriate for mashiac to bring those spiritual things into physicality, and establish himself and rectify the world.

For reference, The Way of G-d, Mashiac Who What Where When How, and perhaps Inner Space.